# loading another program that takes in a textfile in a program subprocess

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, subprocess

I am wanting to load another program into my python GUI.
The other program takes in a textfile and prints out a result
I want to print the result out in my other program
I was just wondering how i would go about this using the subprocess module

is this correct thing to do?

```
def test(self,event):
    t=subprocess.check_output("filename test.py", shell=True)
    wx.StaticText(self,-1,t, (10,35))
```

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: though `check_output()` can be used to get the output of a subprocess; you might not need a subprocess in this case. You could just `import test` and call appropriate functions in it.

Comment: Seems ok to me - doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get the output of a command with subprocess is the [check_output function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output%20check_output):

```
cmd = 'ping 192.168.1.1'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split())
```